# protractor loading multiple browser instance error

Tags: protractor

I'm getting TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'forkNewDriverInstance'

when declaring the new browser instance using:

```
var newBrowser = browser.forkNewDriverInstance(true);
```

I'm using protractor v1.3.1 which is the latest I believe. Can someone help?

So I tried updating to 1.6.1

```
administrators-MacBook-Pro-2$ sudo npm install protractor@1.6.1
protractor@1.6.1 node_modules/protractor
├── jasminewd@1.1.0
├── jasminewd2@0.0.2
├── saucelabs@0.1.1
├── q@1.0.0
├── minijasminenode@1.1.1
├── adm-zip@0.4.4
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.10)
├── glob@3.2.11 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.3.0)
├── source-map-support@0.2.9 (source-map@0.1.32)
├── request@2.36.0 (json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, aws-sign2@0.5.0, qs@0.6.6, oauth-sign@0.3.0, tunnel-agent@0.4.0, mime@1.2.11, node-uuid@1.4.2, form-data@0.1.4, http-signature@0.10.1, tough-cookie@0.12.1, hawk@1.0.0)
├── lodash@2.4.1
├── jasmine@2.1.1 (jasmine-core@2.1.3)
└── selenium-webdriver@2.44.0 (tmp@0.0.24, xml2js@0.4.4)
administrators-MacBook-Pro-2$ protractor --version
Version 1.3.1
```

no errors, but why is it not updated?

Found the answer: if you installed with the -g parameter, then you must uninstall protractor with the -g parameter. Thus it would be

```
$npm uninstall -g protractor
```

after uninstalling 1.3.1 correctly, I was able to install 1.6.1

Answer (score 2):

1.6.1 is the latest version. This is a [1.5.0 feature](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/f9ce40dd2a8cba9e8b30433e61056a96d913041c/CHANGELOG.md#150).